# Angular2 Issues with Async data on static JSON objects

Tags: json, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have a service set up with some static objects that I am using in my UI.

**fetchRulesVariables()**

```
fetchRuleVariables() {

    let variables = [

        {
            name: 'Credit Funding Type',
            id: 1,
            multiple: false,
            hasOperators: true,
            availableOperators: this.fetchOperators('inResults'),
            inputType: 'single',
            placeholder: 'Select a funding type',
            availableValues: this.fetchFundingInstraments()
        }, {
            name: 'Device Trust Score',
            id: 2,
            multiple: false,
            hasOperators: true,
            availableOperators: this.fetchOperators('gtltResults'),
            inputType: 'text',
            placeholder: 'Enter a value between 0 - 100',
            availableValues: ''
        }
    ]
 return variables;
}
```

This object runs another function which adds another array of data to it such as `availableOperators` and `availableValues`. Those too are just static json objects.

In my component, I have a function that is fetching this data by ID using `lodash`.

```
fetchVariableData(id, type) {

    let data = [];

    switch (type) {
        case 'operators':
            data = _.find(this.variables, {id}).availableOperators;
            break;
    }

    return data;

}
```

In my component HTML, I am running an `ngFor` using my function to fetch the results.

```
<li *ngFor="let x of fetchVariableData(1, 'operators')"></li>
```

The issue here is that I am running into some async issues I believe. When I run this, I get an error that `availableOperators` is undefined. If I hardcode the operators into my `fetchVariableData()` function however, it works fine.

How can I handle this async issue where it appears that it is trying to use the `availableOperators` when it isn't ready?

This is all static `JSON`, no HTTP calls.

**Edit1**

Component Code:

```
export class AddRuleComponent implements OnInit {
    variables: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadVars();
        this.renderAddRuleForm();
    }


    loadVars() {
        this.outcomes = this._mserv.fetchOutcomeTypes();
        this.variables = this._mserv.fetchRuleVariables();
    }

    fetchVariableData(id, type) {

        let data: any;

        switch (type) {
            case 'operators':
                data = _.find(this.variables, {
                    id
                }).availableOperators;
                break;
        }
        return data;
    }

}
```

Service Code:

```
fetchRuleVariables() {

    let variables = [

        {
            name: 'Credit Funding Type',
            id: 1,
            multiple: false,
            hasOperators: true,
            availableOperators: this.fetchOperators('inResults'),
            inputType: 'single',
            placeholder: 'Select a funding type',
            availableValues: this.fetchFundingInstraments()
        }, {
            name: 'Device Trust Score',
            id: 2,
            multiple: false,
            hasOperators: true,
            availableOperators: this.fetchOperators('gtltResults'),
            inputType: 'text',
            placeholder: 'Enter a value between 0 - 100',
            availableValues: ''
        }
    ]
 return variables;
}

fetchOperators(type) {

    let operators = [];

    // Based on the set of operators we want
    switch (type) {

        // In Results
        case 'inResults':

            operators.push({
                name: 'In List',
                id: 1,
            }, {
                name: 'Not In List',
                id: 2,
            });

            break;

            // Greater than & Less than
        case 'gtltResults':

            operators.push({
                name: 'Greater Than <',
                id: 3,
            }, {
                name: 'Less Than >',
                id: 4,
            });

            break;

            // Is / is not
        case 'isisnot':

            operators.push({
                name: 'Is',
                id: 5,
            }, {
                name: 'Is Not',
                id: 6,
            });

            break;
    }

    return operators;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
 <select class="form-control input-sm" formControlName="operator" [attr.id]="'operator'+i">
   <option value="">Select an Operator</option>
   <option *ngFor="let o of fetchVariableData(1, 'operators') | values" value="{{ o.id }}">{{ o.name }}</option>
 </select>
```

Values Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'values',  pure: false })
export class ValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
    return Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not an async issue if its all static data and you're not dealing with any promises/observables, etc. Can you post the rest of the code for the component?

Unless you defined it differently elsewhere, you're using a block-scoped variable to define 'variables' with the 'let' keyword. Then, in a different method (outside the block with different scope), you're trying to use 'this.variables' to access it. It has to be set as an instance property for the component for that to work. A variable defined with 'let' basically ceases to exist outside its original scope (method, in this case)

Comment: @diopside Hm, so the `let variables` is defined in my service file. In my component, within my `ngOnInit`, I am running `this.variables = this._mserv.fetchRuleVariables();` In my component, I then access `this.variables` from my code mentioned via `fetchVariableData()`. Does this clear it up any more ?

Comment: What's your `fetchOperators` implementation?

Comment: but you're not returning it, unless I'm not seeing some additional code. You're just using let to define it inside the scope of the method...right? I just tested out something similar with a service and component in my app, and it doesnt work. The this.variables  ends up as 'undefined' after the assignment regardless of what I put in the service method's let declaration.

Comment: @diopside sorry, I omitted the return by mistake in the original post.

Comment: @HarryNinh It returns an object of values, all static data.

Comment: ah. ok.Does it work if you use bracket notation to refer to 'availableOperators'?

i.e   instead of putting  .availableOperators, do    ['availableOperators']

.find(this.variables, {id})['availableOperators']; 

Typescript may be confused bc you haven't told it what availableOperators is anywhere, as you're not using a class or interface or anything.  Try bracket notation and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I'd try to initialize `variables: any = []` first, then do an `*ngIf="variables.length"` on its container.

Out of curiosity, what do you get if you `console.log(id, type)` right after the function definition in **fetchVariableData**, i bet first time might be called without any valid value, therefore the find wont get anything and that's where the undefined comes.

Comment: I think the issue may be in my HTML it self. When I am testing it by hardcoding a id of `1` in the function, it works fine. However, when I change it to a variable to use a form control value such as `<option *ngFor="let o of fetchVariableData(addRuleForm.controls.variables.controls[i].controls.id.value, 'operators') | values" value="{{ o.id }}">{{ o.name }}</option>`, its failing. The path to the value is completely valid though, I can print it right below the input just fine.

Comment: did you make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the lifecycle of your component;

As explained here in [the official guide](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) your **AddRuleComponent** calls ngOnInit() to fetch and initialize the data for the component.

As stated in the docs, the order is **constructor**, **ngOnChanges()**, **ngOnInit()** and so on, so by the time ngOnInit() fetches the values, your component already checked if the properties has been initialized/mutated, that's why **fetchVariableData()** could be called with invalid params (happening from the **ngOnChanges()**) resulting in the undefined error because `_.find(...)` is not returning the **variables** object as you expect.

I'd try to initialize first:

```
variables: any = [];
```

and then do an `*ngIf="variables.length"` on the container, or move the initialization to the constructor.